# Zip output formatting

Tags: zip

I'm learning `zip` and I have run into something I cannot figure out in `man zip`.  When I run `zip -r $folder $folder` it will correctly zip all contents but the zip contents is as follows:

```
zip
|-folder
  |--files
  |--files
```

That is annoying to me and I wanted the zip outcome to be:

```
zip
|-files
|-files
```

Suggestions on being able to create a zip file with the folder name and all contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly through `zip`, but `(cd test && zip -r ../test.zip *)` should do.

Edit: I do not know of an option in zip which allows to the equivalent of `tar -cf test.tar -C test .` (which does exactly what you want).

Answer (score 0):

`zip -rj $folder $folder`

Will remove directories when adding files to the archive. with `info-zip`.

Comment: that works but deletes any folders that may exist.  I'm trying to only prevent the main folder from being duplicated

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I forgot when I asked a friend.   In the loop I had set a `global variable` for the location.  In the `for loop` I forgot to add `cd $folder` before the zip process which caused it to zip the folder and the contents.